# Evoke and Provoke

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's this mean?
Maps and GIS are objects that "evoke and provoke". They do work beyond the desktop of the analyst.

Thanks

Comment: Kinda the difference between "pull" and "push".

Comment: @Hot-Licks Yep... I see that contradiction. just wanted to know what maps and GIS really do to you! Thanks btw

Answer (score 3):

Purely mechanically, evoke suggests bringing or recalling some emotion or feeling and provoke takes on a more negative meaning, of stimulating an emotion, annoyance, or anger in someone. Generally, you can provoke a person [make them annoyed], but you can't evoke a person.

However, in context, it appears that they are using "evoke and provoke" more artistically, to suggest that both Maps and GIS can make a significant impact on the people who view them. This would be a much more stylistic use of those words, and bear almost no resemblance to the actual meanings—with some pass begrudgingly given to "evoke."